# numpy.savez giving an unexpected FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, numpy, file

Im trying to save multiple arrays for later faster access as follows using the numpy.savez.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

iris = datasets.load_iris()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    iris.data, iris.target, random_state = 100, test_size = 0.2,
    stratify = iris.target
)

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train_scaled = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)

np.savez('data/iris_train_scaled', X = X_train_scaled, y = y_train)
np.savez('data/iris_test_scaled', X = X_test_scaled, y = y_test)
```

That code is giving me the following error:

```
File "c:\Users\Montrast\Desktop\c++\.vscode\1.py", line 32, in <module>
    np.savez('data/iris_train_scaled', X = X_train_scaled, y = y_train)
  File "C:\Users\Montrast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 639, in savez
    _savez(file, args, kwds, False)
  File "C:\Users\Montrast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 736, in _savez
    zipf = zipfile_factory(file, mode="w", compression=compression)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Montrast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 103, in zipfile_factory
    return zipfile.ZipFile(file, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Montrast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\zipfile.py", line 1283, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/iris_train_scaled.npz'
```

To my understanding I'm creating a file called 'data/iris_train_scaled' so how come there is a FileNotFoundError.

Comment: does the directory `data` exist?